# How to fill NaN with a value in same row of the data frame using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data have 20 years of values of carbon emission and a column named `average_emission`. I want to replace all `NaN` in a particular row by the corresponding value of `average_emission` of the same row.

```
        1990    1991    1992    1993    1994    1995    1996    1997    1998    1999    ...                                                                           2002          2004    2005        2007          2009      2010    average_emission
0   29.620165   29.847608   25.258152   24.430481   22.996441   22.186615   21.641890   21.500661   19.621534   19.652589   ... 24.975515   24.909066   24.510543   24.964531   24.766706   25.613715   24.750133   24.876706   24.182702   24.344568
2   0.221827    0.194971    0.103776    0.092761    0.083184    0.075646    0.068592    0.061814    0.057051    0.043723    ... 0.041641    0.046108    0.040727    0.054855    0.065816    0.088141    0.158962    0.249074    0.302936    0.101080
3   0.398076    0.380695    0.372921    0.473691    0.307601    0.844306    0.781485    0.534831    0.515117    0.627072    ... 0.786223    0.543084    1.086605    1.069417    1.200877    1.311096    1.369425    1.430873    1.401654    0.794954
4   2.278387    1.215677    0.735198    0.726063    0.601347    0.654537    0.636625    0.490365    0.560271    0.960164    ... 1.229541    1.412697    1.376213    1.412498    1.291548    1.507536    1.580113    1.533178    1.515632    1.130908
5   3.203907    3.284094    3.483917    3.715328    3.735031    3.473291    3.364402    3.168027    3.360498    3.339701    ... 3.579922    3.797800    4.094269    4.206789    4.285595    4.181153    4.373573    4.575251    4.764912    3.775633
6   28.711160   29.798843   28.794559   31.007791   32.672833   30.057582   16.638557   16.047240   29.810631   27.173954   ... 24.956551   29.467089   28.481437   25.914587   23.954519   23.195067   23.033600   21.102296   20.120957   26.636164
7   3.440711    3.525384    3.608582    3.477160    3.569366    3.501875    3.648190    3.758387    3.798782    3.969876    ... 3.253313    3.475035    4.032407    4.111635    4.404525    4.496834    4.744178    4.427960    4.342272    3.853951
8      NaN           NaN    1.174674    0.859707    0.901719    1.083089    0.821585    1.044825    1.094343    0.988512    ... 0.998806    1.129174    1.204567    1.443731    1.459637    1.694755    1.868611    1.469961    1.422998    1.207623
10  4.857267    4.641623    4.566841    4.692005    4.683621    4.721298    4.593864    4.670562    4.496901    4.581279    ... 4.536211    4.804484    4.980996    4.974311    5.096290    5.561525    5.628319    5.906292    6.011269    4.895667
11  15.461262   15.133907   15.322589   15.706018   15.581310   15.600983   16.506006   16.516650   16.940007   17.192235   ... 17.372318   16.906198   17.030341   17.174386   17.293874   17.467002   17.704080   17.631833   16.710904   16.628071
```

Comment: doesn't `df.fillna(df['average_emission'], inplace=True)` work?

Comment: @EdChum No its not working

Comment: You'll have to post raw input data, code to reproduce your df and proof that my code snippet didn't work as I just tried this and it worked

Comment: @EdChum   I have 240+ rows and 23 columns, I applied and not getting NaN removed.
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df1 = df.ix[:,'1990':'2010']
df1['average_emission'] = df1.mean(axis=1)
df2 = df1.dropna(thresh=19)
#df2.fillna(df2.average_emission, inplace= True)
df2.fillna(df2['average_emission'], inplace=True)

also I tried 
df4.fillna(df4.mean(axis=0), axis=0), since I have to place the mean of a row in missing data of that row,  It didn't work.

Comment: Into your question not as a comment, the formatting gets lost in comments, also you're not providing your exact input data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could do:

```
df = df.where(df.notnull(), df.average_emission, axis=0)
```

For example:

```
>>> df
         1990       1991       1992       1993
0   29.620165  29.847608  25.258152  24.430481
2    0.221827   0.194971   0.103776   0.092761
3    0.398076   0.380695   0.372921   0.473691
4    2.278387   1.215677   0.735198   0.726063
5    3.203907   3.284094   3.483917   3.715328
6   28.711160  29.798843  28.794559  31.007791
7    3.440711   3.525384   3.608582   3.477160
8         NaN        NaN   1.174674   0.859707
10   4.857267   4.641623   4.566841   4.692005
11  15.461262  15.133907  15.322589  15.706018
>>> df["average_emission"] = df.mean(axis=1)
>>> df.where(df.notnull(), df.average_emission, axis=0)
         1990       1991       1992       1993  average_emission
0   29.620165  29.847608  25.258152  24.430481         27.289102
2    0.221827   0.194971   0.103776   0.092761          0.153334
3    0.398076   0.380695   0.372921   0.473691          0.406346
4    2.278387   1.215677   0.735198   0.726063          1.238831
5    3.203907   3.284094   3.483917   3.715328          3.421812
6   28.711160  29.798843  28.794559  31.007791         29.578088
7    3.440711   3.525384   3.608582   3.477160          3.512959
8    1.017190   1.017190   1.174674   0.859707          1.017190
10   4.857267   4.641623   4.566841   4.692005          4.689434
11  15.461262  15.133907  15.322589  15.706018         15.405944
```